# Kafka Exactly-Once and compression

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, exactly-once

I think I understood that idempotence means "each message is *written* once" in the log, but when talking about EOS (Exactly-Once *Delivery* Semantic) also the consumer plays a role and enters in the end-to-end guarantees.

So, as stated [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) (for instance), both idempotence and transactions are needed and sufficient for "end-to-end exactly-once semantics".

However, Kafka [doc on compression](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression) says:

> Since data is stored in compressed format on the broker, valid fetch
> offsets are the compressed message boundaries. Hence, for compressed
> data, the consumed offset will be advanced one compressed message at a
> time. This has the side effect of possible duplicates in the event of
> a consumer failure.

Question:

- Even if the producer is idempotent and the consumer is transactional within Kafka (eg Kafka Streams), I may see duplicates since the offset is advanced on the compressed message boundaries. Consider processing a single message not at the boundary of the compressed message: the offset is not advanced and therefore I will see duplicates if the consumer fails. Correct?

It seems that enabling compression may nullify the EOS efforts. I see no mention of this in articles discussing EOS.

Comment: Great question. Doesn't it say further down in the blog the offset per consumer is stored as an internal/system topic?

Comment: It is, but does that change something?